# WPF ListView inside Grid, scrolling error - An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have A ListView with a a few hundred items, if i scroll fast down the items via the mouse on the scrollbar thumb I get this error :

**An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source**

This is my listView

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_emails"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Background="{x:Null}"
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
        BorderThickness="0"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        SelectionChanged="lv_emails_SelectionChanged"
        SelectionMode="Single">
```

Content is loaded in Window_Loaded there is no threading going on :

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    emails = new List<eml>();
    lv_emails.ItemsSource = emails;

    // get the emails of the selected folder and show them in the ListView
    eml em;
    foreach (string fi in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        string[] split = fi.Split('}');//[0]path, [1]uid, [2]email, [3]date, [4]subject
        string disp = split[2] + " " + split[3] + " " + split[4]; 
        em = new eml { filePath = fi, id = split[1], emailAddress = split[2], date = split[3], subject = split[4] };
        emails.Add(em);
    }
}
```

How can I stop this error and why is it happening?

Comment: You are adding items to emails after you set it as the ItemsSource. I don't think the items you add from the subsequent loop are going to appear in the ListView unless set the ItemsSource property after the loop has added all the items to the List. On the other hand, if you just want the ListView to automatically update with changes to the underlying collection then consider using BindingList<T> or ObservableCollection<T> rather than just List<T>.

Comment: I agree. @blins I think you should post your comment as an answer. If you use ItemsSource you need to use some kind of observable collection. You could add the items directly to the list's Items collection instead, but the observable collection is the preferred way.

Comment: @blins indeed I was declaring ItemSource before loading the data, silly mistake as im always using Observable Collections, List caught me out. If you add comment as answer I will mark it as such thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the ListView's ItemSource to an empty List.

Move the line `lv_emails.ItemsSource = emails;` to after your loop.

Alternatively you could bind to the proper collection type as I mentioned in my comment.